# Mongoose: I want to populate a property, that's an array of object references

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var CommentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
created: Date,
user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
body: String,
news: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Newsletter'},
reply: [{ **//I want to populate the user into reply array**
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
    body: String,
    created: Date
    }]
});
```

I'm populating my comments and I also want to populate the user on every index of the reply array. Would I have to do it on the same post call or a different post call?

```
router.post('/reply', auth, function(req, res) {
var reply = req.body;
reply.created = new Date();
reply.user = req.payload.id;
console.log(reply);
Comment.update({_id: reply.comment}, {$push: {reply: reply}})
.populate({
    path: 'user',
    model: 'User',
    select: 'username name facebook.photo images'
})
.populate({
    path: 'reply',
    model: 'user',
    select: 'username name facebook.photo images'
})
.exec(function(err, result) {
    if(err) return res.status(500).send({err: "Issues with server, re: reply"});
    if(!result) return res.status(400).send({err: "Could not post reply"});
    res.send(reply);
})
})
```

Comment: You can only use populate with queries, not an update.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up fixing the problem by adding  `reply.user` to the populate in the get call. That made sure it reached for all of the schema to bring back the user.